# Codeception code coverage not including all classes correctly

Tags: laravel-5, codeception

I am running codeception code coverage. I am running it like:

```
./vendor/bin/codecept run --env testing --coverage-html
```

The HTML is generated in **tests/_output**, but some of the methods that are not covered (I am absolutely sure about it, I triple checked) just show in white colour in the coverage. They are not shown in red or green and are considered covered by the total percentage.

If I remove all tests that cover some class, then the whole class is considered not covered, but if I have at least one test for a class, then the whole class is considered covered, even though only one method is.

I am running Codeception with Laravel5.2

Comment: Downvoter, could you please elaborate why the downvote? What is wrong with my question?

Comment: The question is what version of PHP you are you using and what version of xDebug you are using. I think in latest version there are some problems with showing correct code coverage

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I am using Laravel's Homestead box. PHP 7, xDebug 2.4.0 and Codeception 2.1

Comment: So please take a look at https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/issues/453 - this is my issue with invalid code coverage for same php/xdebug configuration

Comment: Thanks, I will check it. Hopefully it's fixed by the version